# Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK+3 what does it mean

Tags: java, calendar

Trying to understand the Calendar API. I have a legacy code which has below values:
**Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK+4)**.
I know that Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK returns constant value 7 which can be passed to
...get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) and it returns a number which day it is(Like Sunday - it returns
1). But trying to understand why they have used above addition to DAY_OF_WEEK. Can anyone
explain?

Comment: Makes no sense, at that point it is `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` because that has the value 11 (7+4). Are you sure you have not missed some parenthesis somewhere or the code is actually doing something else?

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I'm sure.. The same what I have posted

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` or other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Ya. We are in process of migrating. So this was coded in legacy codebase for which I am looking to get the equivalent output with LocalDateTime/LocalDate

Comment: As others have said it’s most likely a bug and does not do anything useful. If you give more context, we may be able to guess at other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it is an error and the correct code is:

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)+4
```